# Characterization of dimension over $\mathbb{Q}$ of infinite sums of rational functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, vector-spaces, rational-functions

Let $P(n)=(n+r_1)(n+r_2)...(n+r_k)$ be a polynomial with simple, rational, negative roots (i.e. $r_i>0$) and degree $k\geq 2$ (I stick with negative roots as I don't have to worry about dividing by $0$). My question is: What can we say about the dimension of the set

$$S=\text{span}\left\{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{P(n)},\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{P(n)},...,\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^{k-2}}{P(n)}\right\}$$

over $\mathbb{Q}$ in terms of the roots $r_1,r_2,...,r_k$? Any characterization past the cases done below would be helpful.

Work so far: For the case $k=2$, it is not hard to show that

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+a)(n+b)}=\frac{\psi(a)-\psi(b)}{a-b}$$

(where $\psi(x)$ is the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)). Since this is an increasing function for $x>0$ we know

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+a)(n+b)}=\frac{\psi(a)-\psi(b)}{a-b}\neq 0$$

and therefore the dimension can only be $1$. In fact, we can use this fact to prove the dimension is never $0$. Assume by way of contradiction that there exists a polynomial $P(n)=(n+r_1)(n+r_2)+...+(n+r_k)$ such that

$$\dim\left(\text{span}\left\{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{P(n)},\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{P(n)},...,\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^{k-2}}{P(n)}\right\}\right)=0$$

(i.e. all of the elements are $0$). Then pick rationals $a_i$ such that

$$Q(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{k-2}a_i n^i=(n+r_3)(n+r_4)+...+(n+r_k)=\frac{P(n)}{(n+r_1)(n+r_2)}$$

Since the dimension of the space is $0$, we know

$$0=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{P(n)}\sum_{i=0}^{k-2}a_in^i=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{Q(n)}{P(n)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+r_1)(n+r_2)}\neq 0$$

(which follows from the $k=2$ case). And finally, for the $k=3$ case, a [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/254417247_On_the_Transcendence_of_Infinite_Sums_of_Values_of_Rational_Functions) by Saradha and Tijdeman proves the sum is rational if and only if all the roots are integer lengths apart. Using this, it is possible to show that the dimension is $1$ if and only if the roots are integers lengths apart (otherwise the dimension will be $2$). This pattern extends to higher $k$ as well: For $k\geq 3$, the dimension of $S$ is $1$ if and only if all roots of $P(n)$ are integer lengths apart (this takes more effort to prove but it is indeed true).

For all other $k\geq 4$, the question seems much more difficult.

Motivation: I already submitted this as a question on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3891340/dimension-over-mathbbq-of-infinite-sums-of-rational-functions) (including a bounty) but did not receive any answers/comments pertaining to the dimension question (which is the main focus of the post). A colleague suggested that I might have better luck on mathoverflow as they felt this question was much more research oriented than is generally found on stackexchange.